# bundle not found exception being thrown while running the eclipse project

Tags: java

Why is my properties file after being saved is showing as .properties.txt in the eclipse project. I have placed the file in the src folder of my package but still there is an exception thrown for bundle not found.

```
package array;
import java.util.*;
public class AddingToList {
static public void main(String[] args) {

    String language;
    String country;

    if (args.length != 2) {
        language = new String("en");
        country = new String("US");
    } else {
        language = new String(args[0]);
        country = new String(args[1]);
    }

    Locale currentLocale;
    ResourceBundle messages;

    currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);

    messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
    System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell"));
}
```

}

Comment: Rename the file from eclipse and remove the *.txt* from the end.

Comment: renaming is not nececery, how are you trying to retrieve you resourcess? It should contain `/package/../subpackage/resource`

Comment: @R.J..no rename option showing.

Comment: @Antoniossss.....i have not made any sub-package,instead i have copied them in my package folder. I am trying to access them with base name

Comment: @R.J...renaming worked but the program still shows exception. I am pasting my code here. The properties file name is MessageBundle.

Comment: It is probably not present in the classpath.

Comment: @R.J....so how do i correct it??

Comment: as for that message bundle has to be in "default package" + call to bundle should be `"/MessagesBundle"`

Comment: @Antoniossss....yups.!! it worked.!! i had to just provide the package name before the slash..!! thank u..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment to answer and waiting to acceptance:

message bundle has to be in "default package" + call to bundle should be `"/MessagesBundle"`